# Git: Equal number of insertions & deletions - nothing has changed

Tags: git

I have a local repository from where I manually upload files to an FTP. On the remote server, the files are some times changed by a third party. Unfortunately we can not use Git on that server.

To synchronize the changes made by the third party back into my local repository, I download all the files from the remote server and replace my local ones.

This often works great, but at the same time it's also showing me hundreds of files as changed, even though the visible content is exactly the same.

Here is an example screenshot from my Git client (Tower):

[image]

As you can see, Git thinks that every line has changed, even though the content looks the same to me.

Like I said, this happens for hundreds of files and is very inconvenient for me as I like to keep track of things that have actually changed...

Is there a setting in Git or something that allows me to ignore those "changes"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my workflow I figured out the best solution by myself:

```
git diff -b
```

Which seems to ignore all changes in my files that are caused by invisible and control characters.

The way I do it is I enter this command and fix or commit all changes shown. At some point the command shows no more results, and I know that all the other "changes" are actually not relevant for me, and I can discard all the local changes while at the same time being sure that I have commited all the "real" changes to the files to my local repository.

Answer (score 2):

Most commonly this is caused by a line-ending change -- the change is changing the line ending characters from CRLF to LF or vice versa.  This happens when you have windows and non-windows clients using the same repository.

The best way to fix it is to set the core.autocrlf setting appropriately in your .gitconfig.  Alternately, you can use .gitattributes to override user configs.  See the [GitHub help pages](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/)

Answer (score 2):

The changes are most probably caused by line endings getting converted to CRLF when the files are uploaded to the FTP server in ASCII mode. [The FTP RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt) specifies in section 3.1.1.1:

> In accordance with the NVT standard, the <CRLF> sequence should be used where necessary to denote the end of a line of text.

So simply uploading the files in ASCII mode will change their line endings. If git is configured to use just LF as line endings (the default), it will always (correctly) detect these lines as changed. In addition to line endings, the character encoding of the file may change due to these conversions.

To fix it, all FTP clients accessing those files should be configured to use BINARY mode instead. This will avoid any interpretation of the file content and instead just transfer the files as-is.

Alternatively git can be configured to expect a certain type of line endings either through [configuring](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) `core.eol` (in this case presumably to `crlf`) or by writing a matching rule for the affected files into [.gitattributes](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes). While this is more of a workaround, it may be the better solution if it isn't feasible to have all participating parties configure their FTP client appropriately.